# Shuffle / display cards to a blackjack game (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, blackjack

Does you know why "card2" randomly puts a object into the array? It should always put a object into the array.

```js
const cards=[
  {
    card: '&#127137',
    value: '1'
  },
  {
    card: '&#127138',
    value: '2'
  },
  {
    card: '&#127139',
    value: '3'
  },
  {
    card: '&#127140',
    value: '4'
  },
  {
    card: '&#127141',
    value: '5'
  },
  {
    card: '&#127142',
    value: '6'
  },
  {
    card: '&#127143',
    value: '7'
  },
  {
    card: '&#127144',
    value: '8'
  },
  {
    card: '&#127145',
    value: '9'
  },
  {
    card: '&#127146',
    value: '10'
  }
];

var deck = [];

shuffleDeck = () =>{
    var tempDeck = [...cards];
    var card1 = [0];
    var card2 = [0];

    while(0 !== tempDeck.length) {
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempDeck.length);
        card1 = tempDeck.splice(randomIndex, 1);
        card2 = tempDeck.splice(randomIndex, 1); 
        deck = [...card1, ...card2];
      }
}
shuffleDeck();

 for(var i = 0; i <= deck.length; i++){
     console.log(deck[i]);
}
```

Comment: Sry cant understand the main problem, can you be more clear?

Comment: @DiegoVinícius If you run the code snippet multiple times you will see that the array "deck" will show it's content(card1 and card2) but it wont always display card2.

Comment: If you want to show only card1 you should add some conditional on it, they randomly get 2 cards from your tempDeck and always tries to add 2 cards at actual deck, but sometimes get wrong index and just add one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things to fix in your code:

1. In the `while` you set `randomIndex` just once and use it for botth, `card1` and `card2`, but when you set `card1` it uses `splice` and remove that index, so card2 is undefined.
    **FIX**: set `randomIndex` once again after setting `card1`
2. In the `for` loop, you need `i < deck.length` and not `i <= deck.length`, this will avoid an undefined value, because when `i` equals to `deck.length` it would be 2, and deck hasn't index 2, it has only indexes 0 and 1.

```js
const cards = [{card: '&#127137', value: '1'}, {card: '&#127138', value: '2'}, {card: '&#127139', value: '3'}, {card: '&#127140', value: '4'}, {card: '&#127141', value: '5'}, {card: '&#127142', value: '6'}, {card: '&#127143', value: '7'}, {card: '&#127144', value: '8'}, {card: '&#127145', value: '9'}, {card: '&#127146', value: '10'}];

var deck = [];
shuffleDeck = () =>{
  var tempDeck = [...cards];
  var card1 = [0];
  var card2 = [0];

  while(0 !== tempDeck.length) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempDeck.length);
    card1 = tempDeck.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempDeck.length);
    card2 = tempDeck.splice(randomIndex, 1); 
    deck = [...card1, ...card2];
  }
}

shuffleDeck();

for(var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++){
     console.log(deck[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question should be more clear... but running your should and thinking that code should shuffle the deck i guess your mistake is in that line `deck = [...card1, ...card2];` since you are inside a loop, you are just putting 2 cards at the time in your new deck, so at next interation they will ignore the last values and overhide it, you should use `deck.push` to add new cards in deck.

```js
const cards=[
      {
        card: '&#127137',
        value: '1'
      },
      {
        card: '&#127138',
        value: '2'
      },
      {
        card: '&#127139',
        value: '3'
      },
      {
        card: '&#127140',
        value: '4'
      },
      {
        card: '&#127141',
        value: '5'
      },
      {
        card: '&#127142',
        value: '6'
      },
      {
        card: '&#127143',
        value: '7'
      },
      {
        card: '&#127144',
        value: '8'
      },
      {
        card: '&#127145',
        value: '9'
      },
      {
        card: '&#127146',
        value: '10'
      }
    ];

    var deck = [];

    shuffleDeck = () => {
        var tempDeck = [...cards];
        var card1 = [0];
        var card2 = [0];

        while(0 !== tempDeck.length) {
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempDeck.length);
            card1 = tempDeck.splice(randomIndex, 1);
            card2 = tempDeck.splice(randomIndex, 1); 
            deck.push(...card1, ...card2);
          }
    }
    shuffleDeck();
    
    for(var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++){
         console.log(deck[i]);
    }
```